# primefaces datatable using down, up arrow key

Tags: primefaces, datatable, hotkeys

I am developing a project using jsf and primefaces. i need one help that is in using primefaces datatable i want to scroll down each row using up and down arrow keys and also need to check the checkbox using key function.

Is there any options for using keyboard keys and i have used one functionality with delete key and it worked by using hotkey tag I had tried using hotkey bind function with up and down key but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no feature for arrow keys used in the data table may be you can try for example in image swap in primefaces example. This may help you to carry on ur problem.